# Checking if IPv6 is enabled on Windows 7 using C#

Tags: c#, ipv6

I am trying to write a program using C# to act as a multipurpose tool for my company. One of the things we would like in this tool is to determine if IPv6 is enabled/binded to the local area connection network adapter on our Windows 7 machines. I'm not looking for it to have an address, just to know if it enabled or disabled on that adapter. I am unsure as to how to code this. From what I've been able to find online, it seems I should be using System.Net.Configuration and Ipv6Element to check if it is enabled, but I have no idea how to code it. I would like to be able to display if it is enabled or disabled in a text box, so I'm guessing I'd use Boolean values. Could someone point me in the right direction on this? Thanks!

Comment: Disabling ipv6 support on Win7 takes significant surgery, it requires editing the registry by hand.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852

Answer (score 5):

You can test whether the OS supports IPv6 by using this property:

```
bool supportsIpV6 = System.Net.Sockets.Socket.OSSupportsIPv6;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, hmemcpy. When I tried this with a if/else statement, it always returned the true portion of the statement even when I unchecked the box in the local area connection properties. I think I might not have been very specific with my question. I not so much interested in knowing if my OS supports IPv6 as I am knowing that it is enabled/binded to the network adapter. Sorry for the confusion, I updated my question to be more accurate.

Comment: This is the code I tried based off your suggestion.... bool supportsIpV6 = System.Net.Sockets.Socket.OSSupportsIPv6;

            if (supportsIpV6 == true)
            {
                ipStatusTextBox.Text = "IPv4 and IPv6";
            }
            else if (supportsIpV6 == false)
            {
                ipStatusTextBox.Text = "IPv4 Only";
            }

Comment: Please note that this doesn't work on windows XP - in fact it throws a very nasty error ("The procedure entry point _except_handler4_common could not be located in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll")

Answer (score 0):

You can query for exactly what you asked for (if IPv6 is enabled or disabled for a specific network adapter) with the following code using the System.Net.NetworkInformation namespace:

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

// ...

NetworkInterface[] allInterfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
NetworkInterface firstInterface = allInterfaces[0];
bool interfaceSupportsIPv6 = firstInterface.Supports(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv6);
```

Documentation on MSDN: [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.supports(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code to test it. Notice that it tests if the IPV6 is enabled, and not if the Network Card is IPV6 compatible:

```
public static bool InterfaceHasIpv6Enabled(NetworkInterface @interface)
{
  try
  {
    var properties = @interface.GetIPProperties().GetIPv6Properties();
    return properties.Index > -999;
  }
  catch (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInformationException)
  {
    return false;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw ex;
  }
}
```